# Insert elements or remove element from a specified position in 2d-array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d-array of variable number of rows and columns. The array is stored as JSON in the database. I have a requiremnt to add given elements after certain element specified by the user or remove a element specified by the user. Each elemet in the array is unique. The sample json value looks like `[[4,5],[3,1,6,7],[34,21,55]]`. Consider a situation I want to add 2 elements 12,13 after the element 7, the resultant array looks like  `[[4,5],[3,1,6,7,12,13],[34,21,55]]`. And to remove if I given 1 as input the result should be `[[4,5],[3,6,7,12,13],[34,21,55]]`.Using `Gson` I have parsed the json value stored to an array. How can I achieve it in Java with less time complexity.

My code to parse json data from db looks like

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
if (myTemplate.getQuestionOrder() != null) {
    long[][] questionOrder = gson.fromJson(myTemplate.getQuestionOrder(), long[][].class);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following method.

```
private static void insertAfter(long[][] array, int value, long[] insertion) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        long[] sub = array[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < sub.length; j++) {
            if (sub[j] == value) {
                long[] newSub = new long[sub.length + insertion.length];
                System.arraycopy(sub, 0, newSub, 0, j + 1);
                System.arraycopy(insertion, 0, newSub, j + 1, insertion.length);
                System.arraycopy(sub, j + 1, newSub, j + 1 + insertion.length, sub.length - j - 1);
                array[i] = newSub;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found) break;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
insertAfter(questionOrder, 7, new long[]{12, 13});
System.out.println(gson.toJson(questionOrder));
```

This will print `[[4,5],[3,1,6,7,12,13],[34,21,55]]`

To remove an element you can use similar, but slightly modified, logic:

```
private static long[][] remove(long[][] array, int value) {
    boolean found = false;
    int emptyIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        long[] sub = array[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < sub.length; j++) {
            if (sub[j] == value) {
                long[] newSub = new long[sub.length - 1];
                System.arraycopy(sub, 0, newSub, 0, j);
                System.arraycopy(sub, j + 1, newSub, j, sub.length - j - 1);
                array[i] = newSub;
                if (array[i].length == 0) emptyIndex = i;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found) break;
    }
    if (emptyIndex >= 0) {
        long[][] newArray = new long[array.length - 1][];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, emptyIndex);
        System.arraycopy(array, emptyIndex + 1, newArray, emptyIndex, array.length - emptyIndex - 1);
        array = newArray;
    }
    return array.length == 0 ? null : array;
}
```

This method will remove the given item from the inner array and, if the inner array becomes empty, removes it from the outer array. It returns the modified array or `null` if it's empty.

Example usage:

```
questionOrder = remove(questionOrder, 4);
```

Comment: can you mention what we need to remove a particular element

Comment: @SenchuThomas check my udpdate

Comment: Thank you for the help. I find a small difference for example I have an array of [[5]] when I request to remove 5 now the resultant array is [[]]. But actually it wants to be null as it doesnot contain any elements

Comment: @SenchuThomas You're welcome. To return `null` just replace `array[i] = newSub;` with `array[i] = newSub.length > 0 ? newSub : null;`

Comment: when I request to remove 5 from array `[[5]]` after updating the change `array[i] = newSub.length > 0 ? newSub : null;` the result is  `[null]`. I want it to be null also in case the array is `[[5],[7,8]]` the result should be `[[7,8]]`

Comment: @SenchuThomas If you want an empty inner array to be removed from the outer array, you need to remember its index and make a couple of `System.arraycopy` after you exit the loop. Also in this case you have to make the function return a new array - because we can't change the given array's length in place.